# Option selected in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I am using select list. I am trying value to be selected based on the variable data.

```
$scope.auto = "6";
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorsex }">    
        <select id="sex" name="sex" class=" selector form-control" ng-model="formData.sex" required="required"> 
          <option value="Female"  ng-if= "auto == 6" ng-selected="selected">Female</option>
          <option value="Male" ng-if= "auto == 1" ng-selected="selected">Male</option>

        </select>
<span class="errorba" ng-show="formData.errorName">{{ formData.errorsex }}</span>
</div>
```

Issue with the above code is this select box is loading empty.
If i change the code like this.

```
 <option value="Female"  ng-if= "auto == 6" selected="selected">Female</option>
 <option value="Male" ng-if= "auto == 1" selected="selected">Male</option>
```

it is appearing properly but when I submit the form it is not there. I don't know why.

Comment: Try changing `ng-if= "auto == 6"` to `ng-if= "auto == '6'"` or `$scope.auto = "6";` to `$scope.auto = 6;`

Comment: `ng-selected` requires an expression that evaluates to boolean. but you can't combine `ng-model` and `ng-selected`. You should be setting `ng-model` in controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 way for implement this:
1. condition handle  in view:

```
 <option value="Female"   ng-selected="auto == 6">Female</option>
 <option value="Male"  ng-selected="auto == 1">Male</option>
```

2.in controller :

```
$scope.auto == 6 ? $scope.formData.sex="Female" : $scope.auto==1 ? $scope.formData.sex="male":"";
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score -1):

The option will be selected if the expression inside the ng-selected attribute returns true.
Syntax is:

```
<option ng-selected="expression"></option>
```